# Python- Urllib2: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, pyopenssl

Getting the following error when using Urllib2:

[Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

Here is the code:

```
import urllib2   
url = "https://api.thousandeyes.com/";
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, context=ctx);
```

Here is the Error:

```
nnayar$ python test2.py
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 13, in <module>
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url);
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1240, in https_open
    context=self._context)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer>
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Please include the code you're running that is causing the error (and make sure to include the URL or at least the domain you're connecting to).

Comment: updated the question with the details you are looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API recently deprecated TLS 1.0 support which is causing the issue. I am now working on upgrading python to use TLS1.2 which is also very challenging as Mac default install of Python only supports TLS 1.0.